# spring-boot health not showing details (withDetail info)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have written a class implementing HealthIndicator, overriding the health-method. I return `Health.down().withDetail("SupportServiceStatus", "UP").build();`

This should make my `health`-endpoint return:

```
{
    "status":"UP",
    "applicationHealth": {
        "status":"UP"
    }
}
```

Instead it just returns (health, without details):

```
{
    "status":"UP",
}
```

Javacode (somewhat simplified):

```
@Component
public class ApplicationHealth implements HealthIndicator {

  @Override
  public Health health() {
    return check();
  }

  private Health check() {
    return Health.up().withDetail("SupportServiceStatus", supportServiceStatusCode).build();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to spring-boot docs:

> . . . by default, only the health status is exposed over an unauthenticated HTTP connection. If you are happy for complete health information to always be exposed you can set `endpoints.health.sensitive` to `false`.

Solution is to set `endpoints.health.sensitive` to `false` in `application.properties`.

application.properties

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

For >1.5.1 application.properties

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

At Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE (thx `@rvit34` and `@nisarg-panchal`):

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` exposes all endpoints, if that is what you want.

Current documentation can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: For > 1.4.1 I think. Needed the management flag in 1.4.2-RELEASE

Comment: I can see that `management.security.enabled` is present from 1.3.1 in the docs. If more people have exact info it would be appricaiated. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/${version}/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Comment: note `endpoint` vs `endpoints`. That caught me out for a minute.

Comment: Using the `always` value is a work around the issue. Another solution would be to explain how to use the `when-authorized` value, that is, which security configuration would be needed to be authorized.

Comment: Quick fyi, that should be ```include: "*"``` if doing in yml

Answer (score 19):

At Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE:

```
management:
   endpoint:
      health:
        show-details: "ALWAYS"
```

Comment: Via application.properties: 
`management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! I am confused that this is so well hidden in the documentation. It is quite annoying to get status "DOWN" and having no idea why that is.

Comment: I am using Spring 2.1.3 release and below properties in yml solve my issue:  endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: false
  shutdown:
    enabled: true

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"  
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"

Answer (score 9):

Thanks @rvit34 and @Ninja Code Monkey its working.

For Springboot 2.x.x.RELEASE,

Use below for application.properties,

`management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS`

Use below for applicaton.yml,

`management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"`

Answer (score 7):

Setting 'endpoints.health.sensitive' made no difference... had to set:

```
management:
    security:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: I think this is only required since sometime between between 1.4.1.RELEASE and 1.5.1.RELEASE (I just upgraded and had to do this)

Answer (score 3):

For Spring boot 2.X I have following in my application.properties file for detailed information:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
```

Answer (score 3):

need to add

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

to Application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, on version Spring Boot 1.5.9 I had to set

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Spring` version greater than **3X**,
try calling

```
http://localhost:8081/actuator
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8081/actuator/health
```